# Multi-label classification: overlapping or graph structure among labels

Tags: classification, text-mining, multilabel

I am doing multi-label text classification. I have 5000 classes and there is a graph structure among these classes.

How to deal with multi-label classification where there is overlapping or graph structure among labels?

For example, class A may be highly similar to class B, or class C may be more general than class D. The classes are not flat, but they have a semantic structure. A related competition in text classification is https://www.kaggle.com/c/lshtc, where there are 325,056 classes and the classes have a hierarchical structure.

Is there any best practice for this issue?

Many Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple possible interpretations of 'graph structure among the labels'. Could you say more specifically what this means?

Comment: Thanks user20160, I mean there is relation among labels, like hierarchical relation or synonymy relation. For example in the kaggle competition https://www.kaggle.com/c/lshtc, the labels are not flat, they have hierarchical structures.